# Case Looping in PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I want to use a loop to iterate through my array, calling my function to print out all of these messages. I have to somehow keep track - I'm using PHP code.

This my code :

```
<? php
    $count = 6;
    $rp = 11000;
    $amount = array(1000,1000,1500,500,2000,4000);
    foreach ($amount as $v) {   
    echo $total = $rp-$v; ?>
```

my output should be:

```
10000
9000
7500
7000
5000
1000
```

Comment: This is unclear what you're trying to do. What is the problem with the code?

Comment: When you say you "have to somehow keep track", what do you mean? Do you mean you need to calculate the total, or keep count (or both)? You are not using the `$count` variable - how does that factor into what you need? Also, you are missing a `}` which will prevent the code from working at all (I presume this is just a typo in your question?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<?php
$count = 6;
$rp = 11000;
$amount = array(1000,1000,1500,500,2000,4000);
foreach ($amount as $v) {   
   $rp = $rp - $v; 
   $count--;

   //echo $count;
   echo $rp."<br/>" ;
}
?>
```